# why am i getting lower mass after melting iron dust?

Tags: experimental-technique

I've been trying to melt iron dust for a long time but after melting I lose a lot of mass.

Any idea what is causing this?

I've used gas and electrical arc to melt the dust.

Comment: Need more details. How much iron dust are you melting? Are you sure that it is iron and not iron oxide dust? Is there significant gas flow that could be blowing away some of the dust? What is "a lot of mass"? 3%? 10%? 50%?

Comment: BTW--I killed the [fusion] tag and added the only one I could think of that applies better.

Answer (score 0):

"when small particle sizes are involved and a burning fuel is in contact with the melting solids, excessive loss of material by entrainment in the combustion fumes occurs because of excessive gas velocities" (http://www.google.com/patents/US2540593 )